# Redirect to logon view and sign the user out on session timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, redirect, session-timeout

I'm trying to clear the session and sign the user out on session timeout and redirect to the login page. The login page is a partial view returned by the logon method in the account controller.
When the session timeouts, the login view renders in the current page that the user was on before the session timeouts and the same thing with the URL.

Web.Config

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
             <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
             <sessionState timeout="45"></sessionState>
        </authentication>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

BaseController.cs

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext filterContext )
{
    HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

    if(ctx.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if (ctx.Session != null)
        {
            if (ctx.Session.IsNewSession)
            {
                string sessionCookie = ctx.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                if (null != sessionCookie)
                {
                   Session.Clear();
                   FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                   var rr = new RedirectResult(loginUrl);
                   filterContext.Result = rr;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    base.OnActionExecuting ( filterContext );
}
```

I know that I need to do a redirect from the client, but I don't want to add another session timer. Is there anyway to do a "real" redirect from server when the session is timed out?

What I want is when the session times out, the server should clear the current session, sign the user out and show the login view and not render the logon view on current page.

Any tips?

Comment: why not just make both your session and formsauthentication ticket expire at the same time?  Set both timeouts to 45.  Also, if the session times out, doesn't by default, the session become empty?

Comment: That won't work if I want to use slidingexpiration.

Comment: FormsAuthentication is set to use sliding expiration by default as well - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.slidingexpiration(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Isn't this the default behavior already. If the session times out, the user is effectively logged out, as their session cookie will no longer match anything relevant. If they then try to access a page that requires authentication, they will be redirected to the login page to provide authentication. Not sure what the problem here is?

Comment: @ChrisPratt - Session and FormsAuthentication are two different concepts.  FormsAuthentication tickets are encrypted cookies that store relevant login info in the cookie.  Session cookies are simply a session ID that identifies the session data stored on the server.  You can use sessions with anonymous users and you can have FormsAuthenticated users without using sessions :)

Comment: What I want to do is redirect the user to the login view, but the problem is that the login view is rendered on the current view. And when I look at the browser url, it has not changed to "/Account/LogOn". It's like the current page is cached and have the login view injected on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a partial view.
Create a new view "LoginView.cshtml" that renders the login partial view. On `Session_Start` you can check if the user is still logged in. If he is, sign him out and redirect to the new login view.

```
  protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
     {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Response.Redirect("~/Account/LogOn");
     }
  }
```